# How to increase storage size in vmware esxi 6.5 ubuntu 18.04 guest os

Tags: partitioning

I have installed vmware esxi 6.5 and installed guest os ubuntu 18.04 with 2GB ram and 100GB HDD. Now i wnted to increase my HDD to 1TB. From settings i had increased but its not reflecting in the server. still its showing like below.I had used entire disk

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     395M  1.2M  394M   1% /run
/dev/sda2      ext4       98G   12G   82G  13% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop1     squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
tmpfs          tmpfs     395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs          tmpfs     395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [growpart](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/growpart.1.html). It allows you to grow a partition, ex. /dev/sda1, to use all available space, either to the end of the disk, or to where thr next partition starts.

Best practice on virtual disks is to have only one partiton pr disk, because it makes it much easier to expand and mange the disks.